# .htaccess file and folder with the same name Linux

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I have a file named 'Extension' and folder with same name,
i can't go to 'http://www.lolsignature.com/Extension' because that it changes to 'http://www.lolsignature.com/Extension/?Page=Extension' 
my hosting run on linux if that important.

This the part of .htaccess code:

```
#############
# Hot Links #
#############
RewriteRule ^Extension/$ Extension/Index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^signature/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).png$ JavaScript/AJAX/BuildSignature.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^CreateSignature$ JavaScript/AJAX/AddSignature.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?Page=$1 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^rekt/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ JavaScript/AJAX/AddSignature.php?type=$1&region=$2&name=$3&champion=$4&skin=$5 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$
RewriteRule (.*)(.js|.css|.txt)$ Includes/EncryptCode.php?file=$1&exe=$2 [NC]
```

i saw many results with same problem but this not help me :\

basically i want to do if have slash in the end of URL its try go to folder and if not have slash its go to file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should paste the problematic part of your config with your question, as linked content may not be available in the future. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: What URL is it you can't get to?  Which file should it serve?

Comment: @jjmontes i fix my post.